# Java, questions about switches and cases?

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I want to do a certain action 60 % of the time and another action 40% of the time. And sometimes have it doing neither. The best way I can think to do this is through switches and making a bunch of cases. An example is below if this doesn't make any sense to ya'll.
My question is, is there a better way?
Is there a way to just do Case 0-5 does action 1 all in one statement?

```
        Random rand = new Random(50);
        switch(rand.nextInt()) 
        {
        case 1:
        {
            do action 1
        } 
        break;

        case 2:
        {
            do action 1
        }
        break;  
        case 3:
        {
            do action 1
        }
        break;  
        case 4:
        {
            do action 1
        }
        break;  
        case 5:
        {
            do action 1
        }
        break;  
        case 6:
        {
            do action 1
        }
        break;  
        case 7:
        {
            do action 2
        }
        break;  
        case 8:
        {
            do action 2
        }
        break;  
        case 9:
        {
            do action 2
        }
        break;  
        case 10:
        {
            do action 2
        }
        break;  
        }
```

Comment: So basically action 1 gets call more often than action 2, and some times neither of them get called.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would be much more readable IMO:

```
if( Math.random() >= probabilityOfDoingNothing ){

    if( Math.random() < 0.6 ){
        action1;
    }else{
        action2;
    }
}
```

Re. your question about cases, the following is equivalent to your code:

```
Random rand = new Random(50);
switch(rand.nextInt()) 
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    {
        do action 1
    }
    break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    {
        do action 2
    }
    break;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Random rand = new Random(50);

int n = rand.nextInt(11);

if(n<=6)
   do action 1
else
   do action 2
```

You need to use `nextInt(n)` to generate a number between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive). In this case we use 11 which gives us a number between 0 and 10. Anything below 6 (60% chance) we do action 1 otherwise do action 2.

See [this for more details on the Random class.](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/random/random-api.html)

Using a switch statement is only useful if you have a lot of actions you want to perform, where the action performed depends on something. For example a different action is performed based on the current month. Its quicker than writing if-else statements.

Comment: 6:5 is hardly a 60:40 split ;)

Comment: That should have been:
    int n = rand.nextInt(10);

Otherwise you're dealing with 11 values instead of 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you want same action to happen for multiple cases, then don't put break. For example

```
case 1:
case 2:
do action 1; break;
```

In this case, action 1 will happen for both case 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is do not apply break in between like

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
do action 1;
break
case 6:
case 7:
do action 2;
break
default : break;
```

or 
use if-else if you have range of value ..

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to "random" behavior.  Some are easier to implement than others but these sacrifice the entropy bucket. Random() is an expensive operation. Switch is useful for complicated signalling, but for a binary decision if is what you want:

```
int signal = (int)(System.currentTimeMillis() % 5);
if(signal==0 || signal == 1){
 doActionTwo();//one third of the time
}else{
 doActionOne();//two thirds of the time
}
```

Comment: The real question about which implementation comes down to what you are using it for and how important accuracy is to your program.  If a high precision of accuracy, and randomness is important, there are other approaches.